# Display distinct values on a laravel blade view

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.4

I have a prices table that stores the date which a product cost was stored. There is a relationship between the product & price model which works very well by returning the collection. I want to display a table with a date & product name as the columns, then display the **DISTINCT** dates & the corresponding product cost on each row. Below is my blade view code and what the table looks like

view - code

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <th>Date</th>
    @if (isset($products) && !empty($products))

        @foreach ($products as $product) 
            <th>{{ ucwords($product->name) }}</th>

</thead>

<tbody>
        @foreach ($product->prices as $price)            
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $price->date }}</td>
            <td>{{ $price->cost }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach

        @endforeach
    @else
        Product price is not available
    @endif

</tbody>
</table>
```

browser-view
[image]

Changing my code by ending the first foreach loop, gives me something close to what i want but only the cost for the last product is displayed

alternative code

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <th>Date</th>
    @if (isset($products) && !empty($products))

        @foreach ($products as $product) 
            <th>{{ ucwords($product->name) }}</th>
        @endforeach

</thead>

<tbody>
        @foreach ($product->prices as $price)            
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $price->date }}</td>
            <td>{{ $price->cost }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach

    @else
        Product price is not available
    @endif

</tbody>
</table>
```

Browser-view
[image]

How do i display all of my product cost values for each date in the format of the last picture?

Comment: Data is coming from controller so you can use the distinct query in your controller so the data will automatically come distinct from the controller.

Comment: You can define disctinct for combination also

Comment: @PHPGeek I'm getting my values from a model relationship like this public function index()
    `{
        $products = Product::with('prices')->get();

        return view('home', compact('products'));
    }` What I want is the unique dates from the prices table, chaining the unique() to my query throws up an error